# repeticion de una contraseña

Tags: c

yo había hecho un código sobre la simulación de un cajero automático en este use solo por probar una función void que no devuelve nada obviamente, pero tengo un problema, cuando yo ingreso la contraseña tres veces mal, que puede ser cualquiera, el programa me imprime

"error ingreso el pin tres veces mal" junto con "pin incorrecto intenta de nuevo:" y esta oración se repetirá muchas veces si ingreso cualquier número mal, a menos que ingrese el pin correcto ese problema no vuelve a pasar, cuando lo que quiero es que al ingresar el pin tres veces mal, el programa se termine y listo, este es el código que tengo escrito

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void verificarpin(int pin) {
    int intentos = 0;
    int pinCorrecto = 1037;

  
    while (pin != pinCorrecto) {
        intentos++;
        if (intentos == 3) {
            printf("error: ingresaste el pin incorrecto tres veces.\n");
        
        } else {
            printf("pin incorrecto intenta de nuevo: ");
            scanf("%d", &pin);
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int pin;
  
    printf("Ingrese su PIN de 4 dígitos: ");
    scanf("%d", &pin);

    
    verificarpin(pin);
    
    int opc;
    int cuenta = 100000;
    int cantidad;

    do {
        printf("\n***MENU INICIAL***");
        printf("\n1) Extraer dinero\n");
        printf("2) Depositar dinero\n");
        printf("3) Consultar saldo\n");
        printf("4) Salir\n");
        
        printf("digite su opcion a realizar caballero: ");
        scanf("%i",&opc);
        
        switch (opc) {
            case 1:
                printf("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero que desea extraer: ");
                scanf("%d", &cantidad);
                cuenta = cuenta - cantidad;
                printf("Excelente ha extraído %d\n", cantidad);
                break;
        
            case 2:
                printf("Ingrese la cantidad de dinero que desea depositar: ");
                scanf("%d", &cantidad);
                cuenta = cuenta + cantidad;
                printf("Excelente ha depositado %d\n", cantidad);
                break;
        
            case 3:
                printf("Cuentas con un saldo de %d\n", cuenta);
                break;
        
            case 4:
                printf("Salir del programa");
                break;
        }
    } while(opc != 4);
    
    printf("gracias y que tenga un buen día");
    return 0;
}
```

que puedo hacer para que el programa se termine pero si ingreso el pin incorrectamente tres veces y ya?

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! que tu funcion devuelva true o false, y hace un return cuando ya halla 3 ingresos erroneos, y en el main, solo hace un exit si devolvio falso...

Answer (score 0):

Hola si entiendo bien con esto saldria del programa:

```
void verificarpin(int pin) {
int intentos = 0;
int pinCorrecto = 1037;


while (pin != pinCorrecto) {
    intentos++;
    if (intentos == 3) {
        printf("error: ingresaste el pin incorrecto tres veces.\n");
        ***exit(0);***
    } else {
        printf("pin incorrecto intenta de nuevo: ");
        scanf("%d", &pin);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: ya lo probe y funciona, pero hay otro modo de hacer que el programa termine si ingreso el pin incorrecto tres veces sin depender de la palabra exit(0)?

Comment: Para eso deberías hacer que el metodo verificarpin devuelva un valor dependiendo de que se haya introducido el pin correcto o no, y posteriormente cambiar la lógica de main para que dependiendo del resultado de verificarpin continue la ejecución o no